# Android 13 & 14 seem to close WebSocket connection, if i put app in background, after ~20s

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, android-13, android-14

In our Android app we have a VideoCall feature.

We  use 'webRTC' library + i see a 'io.socket:socket.io-client' dependecy.
We have a class 'RtcWrap' (instantiated by DI as a singleton) - this holds the RTCSocket instance + a bunch a socketing & callbacks stuff.

In a specific screen, where we are already in a RTC session (so WebSocket-ing part initiated), we have the feature of receiving messages.
If app is in foreground - we show a view with the message, if app is in background we show a notification.

On Android <13 implementation works, even if you put app in background. On Android 13,14 if we put app in background, after ~20s, connection is lost = WebSocket is closed (and error callback will be thrown)

**I did small experiment** (but with normal sockets): a mini server with a ServerSocket & a client Android app that opens a Socket & both will send messages & print whatever they receive. I can confirm the following behaviour, if you put app in background: on Android <13, connection is kept, while on Android 13 & 14 - connection is closed after some ~20s. (if it helps, i used compileSdk 34, targetSdk 33 + normal sockets: java.net.Socket & java.net.ServerSocket)

For original problem (that was with WebSockets), my "pseudo fix" is to create a foreground Service + ongoing notification.. and basically pass there the 'RtcWrap' instance.

Issue is gone, but I don't like it..
What approaches do you suggest?

Also, how does Android know - that my "socket-ing" is done from a random object held in memory (in my case in the DI graph) or from an object held by a foreground service?

Comment: You have tested that on the emulator or on a physical device? Note that physical devices other than the one from Google may have different behavior to save more battery. https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Real devices, some Samsung

Comment: Samsung is known for an extra ordinary aggressive battery saving thus stopping/killing apps and tasks in background. Therfore comparing devices of different manufacture may expose differences that are caused by the manufacturer not the Android version.